# Rewrite right to left in Ltac or Tactic Notation

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

How does one use fancier versions of the rewrite tactic when defining tactics or tactic notations?

Both of the following produce a `Error: Syntax error: '.' expected after [vernac:command] (in [vernac_aux]).`

```
Ltac rewrite_right n H :=
  rewrite <- n H.

Tactic Notation "rewrite_right" integer(n) hyp(H) :=
  rewrite <- n H.
```

Comment: What should the integer argument do?

Comment: The integer argument controls how many repeated rewrites are done. Ref: End of [rewrite tactic](https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/refman/proof-engine/tactics.html#coq:tacn.rewrite) section in the reference manual.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. This parse error looks like a bug to me. Consider filing a report at https://github.com/coq/coq/issues.

Comment: [Issue](https://github.com/coq/coq/issues/8225) submitted!